# UIButton highlighted not working, when I touched

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I tried to set image, when I touched like this code.

first try is

```
self.penNameAsImageUploadButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_copyright_photo_upload_highligted"), for: .highlighted)
```

seconde try is creating background image as background color.

```
extension UIButton {
func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
    let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: forState)
}
}

self.penNameAsImageUploadButton.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.sqBlack.withAlphaComponent(0.15), forState: .highlighted)
```

seconde way is working well other button. but this button is not working.

It was working, if I touched for 2 second. If I clicked shortly the button, action was working well, but image is not changed. I set some option like boderColor and shadow in code. is this affect to make highlighted state?

Answer (score 0):

Your first code will work:

1: Set image for .highlighted:

```
self.penNameAsImageUploadButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn_copyright_photo_upload_highligted"), for: .highlighted)
```

2: In the action method you need to set `isHighlighted` `true` and `false` accordingly:

```
self.penNameAsImageUploadButton.isHighlighted = true
```

Or

```
self.penNameAsImageUploadButton.isHighlighted = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I tired change background, when button clicked. And then button background color back to original color after 1 second. I'm not sure good way to do. But this is only way to change color, when I touched.

```
@IBAction func reviewAppstoreDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.reviewAppstoreButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorFromRGB(0x1866cb)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1))
    {
        self.reviewAppstoreButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.sqBlue2Appstore

    }
}
```